# The constructor TextView(new View.OnClickListener(){}) is undefined

Tags: java, android, eclipse, textview

I get this error code    `The constructor TextView(new View.OnClickListener(){}) is undefined`
please help me this is my code, its had me stumped for days now.
    `package com.example.tgtidea;

```
public class FrontPage extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_front_page);

    Button btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View v) {

            EditText comment = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            String comment1 = comment.getText().toString();
            TextView textView = new TextView();
            textView.setTextSize(40);
            textView.setText(comment1);

        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.front_page, menu);
    return true;
}

}
`
```

This not all of my code but it is most of it. did some research and it looked like some other people had a similar problem except with Intent instead of Text View. I'm a pretty young programmer i'm only 14 so excuse my ignorance. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this

```
TextView textView = new TextView();
```

to

```
TextView textView = new TextView(FrontPage.this);
```

But your textView is not attached to activity. Have a LinearLayout or RelativeLayout in `activity_frot_page` , initialize it and add textView to it or have textView in `activity_front_page` initialize it and set text to textView

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html

Look at the public constructors in the above link

Answer (score 0):

try something like:

```
mCallButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new FatchItemsTask().execute();
        }
    });
```